# Connecting with Dialogflow V2 api using Python

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es, api-ai

As mentioned in the documentation, I have setup cloud account along with activating the dialogflow API.
Then I activated dialogflow V2 in my dialogflow.com account along with setting the same google project in it.

I downloaded the google credentials in JSON format and set it's path for authentication too accordingly.

After doing all this, when I ran

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
print(buckets)
```

It gave me the error,

```
OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.
```

So, I set the project name in the storage client itself.

```
storage_client = storage.Client(project='[Project-id]')
```

So, that solved the problem with the code, still, I think it should have detected the project-id on its own without having to provide the project id as has been given in the documentation.

After all this, I tried running the below program, to check the connection,

```
import dialogflow_v2beta1
client = dialogflow_v2beta1.AgentsClient()
parent = client.project_path('[Project-id]')
response = client.import_agent(parent)

def callback(operation_future):
    result = operation_future.result()

response.add_done_callback(callback)
metadata = response.metadata()
```

I am getting the following error after this,

```
PermissionDenied: 403 Dialogflow API has not been used in project usable-auth-library before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dialogflow.googleapis.com/overview?project=usable-auth-library then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the API by visiting the URL in the error message?

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Please Set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/libraries

**Examples:**

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/thanhha/owner-project-ab.json"
```

Answer (score 1):

Once we create the Service account Key (which is a json file, lets rename it as **private_key.json**) as per the instructions from https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup?authuser=2

We need to set this in the environment variable as **@ThanhHa** had mentioned. Another alternative to setting the environment variable through the terminal, is, adding the following code to your python code.

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'private_key.json'
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

I was getting the same error, but this fixed it. You just need to set up the authentication. Any questions ask me.

Comment: Can you please let me know in detail as to what you did?